# Sending an HTTP request with headers in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, curl, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build an app that connects to the twitter api. To accomplish this, I need to send a http get request with a set of headers using Angular2.

Note, the below curl requests is successful (assuming the correct keys are in place).

This is what I tried, the only issue is, with the below implementation, I am an unable to pass in the necessary headers.

Was wondering if anybody has encountered this and has any suggestions on how to resolve?

Thanks in advance

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {

}

getTwitterResponse() {
         return this._http.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json')
            .map(res => res.text);
}
```

Curl Request Sample w/ Headers (w/ auth keys removed)

```
 curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="123456", oauth_nonce="123456", oauth_signature="f%123456%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1475158916", oauth_token="123456", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

Comment: that's true for angular1, but angular2 is slightly different

Comment: Yes sir, it is. First param of get is a url, second param must be an instance of RequestOptionsArgs, not of type Header.

Comment: Right, but if you pass in headers to get as a second param, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You add headers to your request like this:

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';    

getTwitterResponse() {

let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';

     return this._http.get(url, options).map(res => res.text);
}
```

Explanation of what's happening here: request `get` of `Http` have the following signature:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs)
```

Second argument is optional and it's type is `RequestOptionsArgs` which is an interface used to construct `RequestOptions`, which means you can pass `RequestOptions` to `get` as a second argument. `RequestOptionsArgs` is an interface with following attributes:

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string;
    method?: string | RequestMethod;
    search?: string | URLSearchParams;
    headers?: Headers;
    body?: any;
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    responseType?: ResponseContentType;
}
```

All attributes are optional and that's why we can pass only `headers` to our `options`. You can change `Content-Type` with anything you want and you can add more than 1 header:

```
headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'First header': 'First value',
    'Second header': 'Second value',
    'Third header': 'Third value',
    'Fourth header': 'Fourth value'
});
```

You can read more about everything I just blabbed about on the following links:

- [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html)
- [RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html)
- [Headers](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/Headers-class.html)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: on the line where I am trying to call this._http, etc. I am getting an error saying "Error during instantiation of AppComponent!", any ideas?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Did your application work before adding what I suggested? I find it hard to believe that adding `RequestOptions` to `get` request could cause `Error during instantiation of AppComponent!` :-) You should post your `AppComponent`.

Comment: Yes it did. I suspect my Angular/npm dependencies may have been updated, however, after updating everything, I am not even able to inject Http into the constructor and I am not getting any errors either. See... https://jsfiddle.net/629cyjp2/1/

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Are you using latest version of Angular?